# EF Core with many to many circular reference relationship inhibiting delete

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been struggling with the following scenario, while using EF Core:

A particular entity, let's call it Person, has a many to many relationship with itself [an instance of Person may contain a list of other Person instances]. 
The join entity embodying this many to many relationship, call it PersonPerson, has been configured with OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.Restrict), 
in order to break the circular reference/cascade delete.  But this seems to be hindering the normal deletion of these PersonPerson instances.

The error is

> InvalidOperationException: The association between entity types 'Person' and 'PersonPerson' has been severed but the foreign key for this 
>   relationship cannot be set to null. If the dependent entity should be deleted, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.

Is this a catch 22 situation, or am I not deleting correctly?

```cs
public class Person
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        -some person properties-

        public ICollection<PersonPerson> Parents { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PersonPerson> Children { get; set; }

}

public class PersonPerson
{
        [Required]
        public int PersonParentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int PersonChildId { get; set; }

        public Person Parent { get; set; }
        public Person Child { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
...
            builder.Entity<PersonPerson>()
                .HasKey(i => new { i.PersonParentId, i.PersonChildId });

            builder.Entity<PersonPerson>()
                .HasOne(i => i.Parent)
                .WithMany(i => i.Children)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentParentId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<PersonPerson>()
                .HasOne(i => i.Child)
                .WithMany(i => i.Parents)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.PersonChildId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
...
```

In the controller, there is:

```cs
Person person;
PersonPerson instanceToRemove;
...
person.Children.Remove(instanceToRemove);
...
_context.Update(person);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Looks like another EF Core bug. If you replace `person.Children.Remove(instanceToRemove);` with `_context.PersonPerson.Remove(instanceToRemove);` it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much @IvanStoev!  It's working.

Comment: Is anyone tracking this on GitHub?  I've got a join table and wanting a similar situation - `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` on both sides of the mapping (because I only want whats on the join table deleted).  But, I get the same error as above in doing so.

Comment: Also, what version of entity-framework-core and tooling are you on?

Comment: I'm asking about version because I've uploaded to 1.1.0 of EF Core and 1.1.0-preview4-final of the tooling.  What once threw a `circular reference relationship` (defining a join table with both sides of the relationship as `Cascade`) when creating a migration no longer does and the delete works fine.